# Geth syncing very slowly in testnet

Tags: go-ethereum

Geth is syncing very slowly in testnet after block 588000. I read that it might be because the testnet is under attack? To fix the problem do I have to delete the current blockchain and download it all over again? or is there an easier way? If I let geth keep syncing in this very slow rate will it pick up the pace later?